# PHP duplicate check - isUnique()

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, duplicates

```
function isUnique($email){
    $query = "select * from registerform where email='$email'";
    global $db;

    $result = $db->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        return false;
    }
    else return true;

}

function isUnique($username){
    $query = "select * from registerform where username='$username'";
    global $db;

    $result = $db->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        return false;
    }
    else return true;

}
```

error code: Cannot redeclare a function previously declared, how do I make it check the duplicate for email and username?

if I remove 1 of the code it is completely fine.

Comment: You can not use same name for function name.
You can use `isUniqueEmail` and `isUniqueUsername` as function name so it will not throw error.

Comment: This is open to (sql) injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help, fixed it.

Comment: Please don't overwrite your question!

Comment: @Lithilion Right; I rolled it back.

Comment: @ModuTollens why did you roll back to a bad revision? I rolled it back also to the right one. I am rolling back to the original "again".

Comment: The only possible way to do this correctly is to add a UNIQUE key in MySQL.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I rolled back at the same time, the link changed so fast I couldn't stop my finger from pressing the wrong rollback link. Sorry.

Comment: @ModusTollens Things roll pretty fast on Stack eh? *lol!* - No worries :)

Comment: sorry my bad , as i thought it was a dumb mistake that should not appear on this site.

Answer (score 3):

You could also make a generique function such as

```
function isUnique($field, $value)
{
    $query = "select * from registerform where $field='$value'";
    global $db;

    $result = $db->query($query);

    return $result->num_rows > 0
}
```

You should also check how to sanitize inputs => https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Thanks for the help, fixed it . will try your method too ! thanks

Comment: It is considered better practice to pass the connection as an argument to the function, instead of using `global`. This is also open to SQL injection. Last little nitpick, you can use `return (bool)$result->num_rows;`and achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

You have to rename the function name, e.g.: `isUniqueEmail` and `isUniqueUsername`

You cannot have two functions with the exact same name.